# Sending a JSON-package via TCP from a html website

Tags: javascript, python, html, json, tcp

I have to send a JSON-package via a TCP-connection to a embedded system in my local network. I have a python script running on this embedded system, so it acts like a server and is responding with another JSON-package.

what possible solution is there to send and recieve data after clicking on a button on this website.

```
<button class="btn" onclick="Auswahl('Quit')" href="">Quit</button>
```

This is what my button should look like and the json should be in a format like this:

```
{"Mode":"Modus","Debug_cmd":"String"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide an HTTP server to get your XHR request and connect to your TCP server from your backend TCP server, this could be achieved by a simple http://flask.pocoo.org/ route.

Another solution is to provide a Websocket connection which is not supported in older browsers. for that you may use Twisted or Tornado or you can use simple lightweight libs in your current python script.

But there is no way to establish a TCP connection out of the HTTP or WS  in browsers.

Comment: so i tried it with twisted, but my problem is, that I want to send data back to the client periodicly and get this data from a queue. In my understanding twisted is build on reacting to events. Is there a way to send data every let's say 30 ms? or is tornado a better solution for my problem?